# ORCHARD: Displaying specific widgets for an Error/NotFound and the LogOn page

Tags: orchardcms

I was having trouble figuring out how to get widgets specific to the error/notfound.cshtml pages I have put into my custom theme.

There is no "url" per se, so it's not like I could create a layer rule for it.  Is there a specific way to do it.

Also, while I beleieve I could create a url rule such as url("/LogOn"), my url's for log on are appended with a "?ReturnUrl=%2F". Will that matter, or should I just do url("/LogOn*")?

All the widgets in my "Default" layer appear fine on these pages. But for some parts of pages I don't use "Defualt" because there are different versions of each of those widgets. I want to display some content in these zones that are empty (because they are not "Default" widgets).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your own rule, based on the code for the url rule.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be something that could be done in the admin screen in the layer rule section.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is a rather uncommon scenario. Fortunately the extensibility point exists.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble, wondering if you could help with this: I took your LayoutFilter.cs and Layout.cshtml from the CustomThemeMachine (your post on Switching layouts). I then tried inserting them into the Fail parts of your Vandelay.Industries 1.4 module. I just changed the filter to FailLayoutFilter.cs. And I made the layout be Layout-Vandelay_Industries-Fail.cshtml. Both were added to the .csproj file. But it's not even picking it up. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. Did you set breakpoints in there? Are there maybe OrcharfFeature attributes that need to be removed?